# deserializing array always returns null for the element but works with attributes

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, serialization, deserialization

I've got a problem when deserializing partially works. When I have an xml node with attributes, all the attribute values get loaded correctly into my class but when I use elements, it just returns null.

I have the following stored in an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
  <from>admin@company.com</from>
  <recipients>
    <recipient>user1@company.com</recipient>  
    <recipient>user2@company.com</recipient>
  </recipients>
  <subject>Test subject</subject>
  <body>Test body</body>
  <attachments>
    <attachment>c:\test.txt</attachment>
    <attachment>c:\test1.txt</attachment>
    <attachment>c:\test2.txt</attachment>
  </attachments>
</email>
```

My main class is defined as follows:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("email")]
public class EmailNotification
{
    [XmlElement("from")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("body")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("recipients")]
    [XmlArrayItem("recipient")]
    public List<EmailNotificationRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("attachments")]
    [XmlArrayItem("attachment")]
    public List<EmailNotificationAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    public EmailNotification()
    {
        this.Attachments = new List<EmailNotificationAttachment>();
        this.Recipients = new List<EmailNotificationRecipient>();
    }
}
```

Here is my recipient class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailNotificationRecipient
{
    public EmailNotificationRecipient()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement("recipient")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not going to bother displaying the attachment class as it is identical in regards to its definition as the recipient class.

All the simple elements are being filled correctly and my array is being build but all the elements are null inside it.

When debugging, I can see that my arrays have 2 items for the recipients and 3 items for the attachments but when I check the value inside, each of the array item are null.

I've also added a constructor the EmailNotificationRecipient class and set a breakpoint on it and it hits my breakpoint every time for each defined recipient.

With the above 2 points, it would make you believe that everything is ok with my class definitions or it would not manage to find the correct number of elements but as mentioned, all objects within my array are set to null even though the correct number of objects are created.

Originally I had the `XmlArrayItem` defined with the type:

```
    [XmlArrayItem("recipient", typeof(EmailNotificationRecipient))]
    public List<EmailNotificationRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
```

I removed it to see if it would make any difference, but to no avail.

What am I missing? This is driving my bonkers!!!

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

See answer below from @NoIdeaForName.

The way I currently have it defined would have meant that in order for it to return a value, my xml should have looked like:

```
<recipients>
  <recipient><recipient></recipient></recipient>
</recipients>
```

as my array is expecting a class recipient when in fact all I have within each recipient node is a string, so the array should have been defined as follows:

```
    [XmlArray("recipients")]
    [XmlArrayItem("recipient")]
    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
```

Now on the other hand, if each of my recipients in my xml were defined like this:

```
 <recipients>
  <recipient>
    <fname><fname>
    <lname><lname>
  </recipient>
</recipients>
```

then it would make sense to define a separate class the way I had it i.e. EmailNoticiationRecipient, but instead of having recipient as a property, you would have fname and lname.

Thanks again @NoIdeaForName :)

Comment: is EmailNotificationAttachment serializable? cus' if not there is your problem. add to that the inside of the recipient tag is not in any tag so i don't think the deserializer knows what to do with it

Comment: i'll write an answer, but i can't check it ATM, so lemme know what happend so i'll know if to delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said you are doing

```
[XmlArray("attachments")]
[XmlArrayItem("attachment")]
public List<EmailNotificationAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }
```

in the `EmailNotification` class and your `Attachments` class is

```
[Serializable]
public class EmailNotificationRecipient
{
    public EmailNotificationRecipient()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement("recipient")]
    public string Recipient { get; set; }
}
```

that means your xml should look like:

```
  <recipients>
    <recipient><recipient>user1@company.com</recipient></recipient>   
    <recipient><recipient>user2@company.com</recipient></recipient> 
  </recipients>
```

because in every `recipient` tag there is a class and in every `recipient` class should be a property name(tag as) `recipient`

the best way to check it would be to create a class with values and serialize them and see how the output looks like

Comment: Hi, You are probably correct. I thought about that earlier on as my code had something like attachment.attachment when looping through the attachments. I really don't like this. I'll go & research and try to figure out how I cna handle this as need to keep the xml as is.

Comment: I've just checked and you are correct. I'm confused as I thought the way I defined my classes was correct???

Comment: ok, I fixed it! I changed my list to be of type string instead of a specific object. I guess it makes sense as I only have one value inside the recipient node. If each recipient had sub-elements i.e. name, firstname, etc... it would have made sense to create class containing these and have a list of recipient instead containing these properties. Thanks again for highlighting this! I'll update my answer

Comment: @Thierry yep, i was about to tell you a list of string would work. anyway if that's the case please accept my answer